# show content in a modal / popup window

Tags: views, javascript

I'm using views in my drupal site and I want to show a popup window containing custom information (the information from the content type I guess) when I click on a view item.

Something really similar to this: http://conference.99u.com/#speakers

Is there an easy way to do this in Drupal? Which is the best module for that?

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sounds like [colorbox_node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) might be the module you want.

> Gives the user the ability to display ANY page inside a colorbox modal
>   without the header and footer. Those pages include:
>
> - Node Pages
> - User Pages
> - Views Pages
> - Webforms (requires Webform Ajax Module)
> - Integration with Views
> - Integration with Context
> - Integration with Panels